# IIS 7.5 hierarchy breaks application path

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7.5

I've setup a web application under a website using information from [IIS.Net - Understanding Site, Applications and Virtual Directories](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis)

Below is what they say regarding applications.

> An application is a group of files that delivers content or provides services over protocols, such as HTTP. When you create an application in IIS, the application's path becomes part of the site's URL.

That's great; exactly what I want; however...the application path is not resolving properly for script files, css and a web service I have in the application.

For `http://site_name/application_name`

```
<img src="/Content/images/smiley.png" alt="smiley face" /></a>
```

resolves to

`src="/site_name/Content/images/smiley.png"`

instead of

`src="/application_name/Content/images/smiley.png"`

As a work-around I've wrapped the paths I was using withe `@Url.Content()` helper. Not the prettiest solution, but it's working.

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/smiley.png")" alt="smiley face" /></a>
```

Is there a way to fix this in IIS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `@Url.Content` is the right way here IMO.  It then makes the links work regardless of how a developer is setup on their machine (running the dev server, or using IIS).

I'm not sure if there's a way to deal with it in IIS, maybe a URL rewrite rule, but it won't help with consistency across development machines.

Edit: You could deploy the site to the root of the site in IIS, as opposed to a virtual directory, but that is only a good solution if you're only going to be hosting this single site.

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to make sure this was an acceptable work-around if anything.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an IIS issue, this is something you'd have to do on the template side.  Now,  I'm not sure, but in asp.net mvc4/razor 2 there might be some additional magic that allows you to instead of

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/smiley.png")" alt="smiley face" />
```

do

```
<img src="~/Content/images/smiley.png" alt="smiley face" />
```

and everything is converted automatically to the proper path.  Actually [this blog post](http://www.davidhayden.me/blog/asp.net-mvc-4-the-new-tilde-slash-feature-in-razor-2) seems to document that ability.

But but otherwise, `<img src="/path/to/image.png" alt="smiley face" />` is always going to refer to `http(s)://(current server)/path/to/image.png`, unless, somehow the html is *rewritten* before it is seen in the browser.

Comment: That's good to know about MVC4/razor 2. Too bad I can't use it for this project. But from you and @gromer say, it seems like the work-around I'm using is the way to go. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add this "base" tag in your "head" section: `<base href="~/" target="_blank" />`. I was having the same problem with my anchor elements.